# Showing when a permutation matrix is diagonizable over $\mathbb R$ and over $\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

For a permutation $\sigma$ of the set $\{1,...,n\}$, and consider the $n \times n$ matrix $A_\sigma$, where the $i^{\text{th}}$ column is the standard vector $e_{\sigma (i)}$.  For which $\sigma$ is $A_\sigma$ digonizable over $\mathbb{C}$, and which values for $\mathbb{R}$?

I don't exactly know what I should do.  I think I should use the fact that a map is diagnizable iff the characteristic polynomial of t factors in linear factors over the field I'm in, and if $m_g(\lambda)=m_a(\lambda)$ for all eigenvalues

If anyone could start me up or help me out or do one of the examples it would be appreciated, thanks!

Small edit: I don't even know what the matrix looks like, maybe it's just me but I don't find it's clear

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, do you know what a permutation on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ is?

Comment: Yes I believe so, it's similar to reordering of elements so we could have 1 map to 2, 2 map to 3, and 3 map to 1 (assuming n=3) so then $\sigma(1)=2$, $\sigma(2)=3$, $\sigma(3)=1$.  It must also be a bijection.  Maybe my definition or idea of what it is isn't correct, or the right way to think about it.  Are my columns simply different orderings of ${1,...,n}$, where one column (the $i^{th}$) is ${1,...,n}$ in that order? @GitGud

Comment: Exactly. For instance with $n=3$ and the $\sigma$ you described, you'd get $A_\sigma=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 &1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I see why that is, so all matrices would have only one 1 and the rest all 0's?  Thanks I'll try to work with his @GitGud

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you fall on this problem?

Comment: Practice problem for a midterm coming up, definitely one of the harder ones he recommended

Comment: Sorry can't edit my comment look above @PatrickDaSilva

Comment: @Jeff: I think you need the _ minimal_ polynomial to split, not the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not hard to check that $A_{\sigma}$ has finite order for each $\sigma \in S_n$, where $S_n$ denotes the group of permutations of the set $\{1,\cdots,n\}$. This is because it is not hard to check that $A_{\sigma}^m = A_{\sigma^m}$, where $\sigma^m$ denotes the $m$-fold composition of $\sigma$ with itself. I don't know how much you are aware of representation theory, but it is a general result of the theory of representation of finite groups that given a (complex) representation $\rho : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$, for each $\sigma \in G$, $\rho(\sigma)$ is diagonalizable. I will sketch the proof below, in case you don't know about this. (I will not use the language of representation theory, only complex linear algebra.)

Let $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ be the $\mathbb C$-basis of $\mathbb C^n$ over which you write $A_{\sigma}$ as normally, i.e. so that $A_{\sigma}(e_i) = e_{\sigma(i)}$. Let $\langle - ,-\rangle$ denote the standard Hermitian inner product on $\mathbb C^n$, and define a new Hermitian inner product $(-,-)$ on $\mathbb C^n$ via
$$
(x,y) \overset{def}= \frac 1{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \langle A_{\sigma} x, A_{\sigma}y \rangle. 
$$
It is an easy check that $(-,-)$ satisfies the axiom of an Hermitian inner product (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html)). Now since it is an Hermitian inner product, there exists an orthogonal basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ with respect to $(-,-)$. Then under this basis, for $\pi \in S_n$, we have
$$
(A_{\pi}v_i, A_{\pi}v_j) = \frac 1{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \langle A_{\sigma}(A_{\pi} v_i), A_{\sigma}(A_{\pi}v_j) \rangle = \frac 1{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \langle A_{\sigma} v_i, A_{\sigma}v_j \rangle = (v_i, v_j) = \delta_{ij} 
$$
because summing over all permutations of the form $\sigma \pi$ is the same as summing over all permutations of the form $\sigma$. It follows from this that the vectors $\{A_{\pi}v_1,\cdots,A_{\pi}v_n\}$ are pairwise orthogonal under $(-,-)$, so that the matrix of $A_{\pi}$ over the basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is **unitary** with respect to $(-,-)$, thus diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$.

Remark : You can also check that since $A_{\pi}^{n!} = A_{\pi^{n!}} = I$ the identity matrix, all the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A_{\pi}$ will satisfy $\lambda^{n!} = 1$, i.e. they are $n!$-roots of unity. (The number $n!$ is just to be safe ; for most eigenvalues the number will be actually much smaller, and $n!$ is actually never attained since $S_n$ is not a cyclic group.) I don't know much about representation theory over the real numbers, but there is probably a well-understood theory of this. I would be surprised that someone into real representation theory would not have characterized this already.

Hope that helps,

Comment: This makes more or less sense, I'm going to have I read it a few more times to get it completely, and after the representation theory part I have seen the concepts behind everything shown.  Out of curiosity how do you come up a definition for the inner product like that?  Is it through practice, experience and intuition, or is there a process of actually doing it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this prove diagonalizability over $\mathbb{R}$ as well ? I'm not able to figure out where this argument might break.

Comment: @Jeff : It is a very standard representation theory trick. To give you an idea, in the introductory book of Serre "Linear representations of finite groups", it is on page $4$. (This book can be read with a good background in linear algebra and basic group theory, so don't be scared by Serre's name, if you know him.)

Comment: @Srinivas K : I was about to start to write something about it, and Olivier Bégassat just said everything there is to say about it. Read his answer!

Answer (score 8):

This adresses the question of diagonalisability over $\Bbb R$. Over $\Bbb C$, there is no problem, since $A_\sigma^m=I_n$ where $m$ is the order of $\sigma$ in the group $S_n$, and thus $A_\sigma$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$.

---

Use the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$ : if $\sigma=c_1\cdots c_p$ where the $c_i$ are cycles with disjoint support, then you can rearrange the standard basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ so that the supports of the $c_i$ are "together and in order". This shows that $A_\sigma$ is conjugate to a matrix like so
$$\begin{pmatrix}C_1\\&C_2\\ &&\ddots\\&&& C_p\end{pmatrix}$$
where each $C_i$ is the matrix
$$C_i\;=\begin{pmatrix}
0&&&&&1\\
1&0\\
&1\\
&&&\ddots&\\
\\
&&&&1&0\end{pmatrix}_{l_i\times l_i}$$
where $l_i$ is the length of the cycle $c_i$. This matrix has minimal polynomial $X^{l_i}-1$.
Thus, the minimal polynomial of $A_\sigma$ is
$$\mu_{A_\sigma}=\mathrm{lcm}\,(X^{l_1}-1,X^{l_2}-1,\dots,X^{l_p}-1)$$
Since $X^n-1$ has non real roots for all $n\geq 3$, $A_\sigma$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ iff $\sigma$ is a (possibly empty) product of disjoint transpositions, i.e. $$A_\sigma \text{ is diagonalizable over } \Bbb R \Longleftrightarrow\sigma^2=\mathrm{id}$$

Comment: Great! I didn't bother giving it a thought because I usually say **no** whenever I see things over the real numbers.. but it turned out quite simple! +1

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thank you : )

Comment: What do you mean by support of $c_i$ ?

Comment: @user371231 The support of a permutation is the complement of the set of fixed points.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Making a permutation on the column of a matrix $A$ amounts to right multiply $A$ by a permutation matrix $P$, which is invertible. Do you see why? To which matrix would you apply  $P$ to obtain $A_{\sigma}$?

Comment: Well I think the permutation would be invertible because you could always change rows to get the identity in P?

Comment: It's invertible for a less computational reason: you can revert back to $A$ by applying the inverse permutation.

Answer (score 1):

Terminology : A matrix $M$ is said to be diagonalizable if thre exists an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $M=P^{-1}DP$ 
Spectral Theorem : A Matrix $M$ is Unitarily diagonalizable iff it is normal i.e., $MM^*=M^*M$
 
Not an answer but an experiment. It's too big to put in the comments area and that's why I'm posting it here

**Case n = 2 :** Both are symmetric. So they are diagonalizable.
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  &0  \\
    0  &1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0  &1  \\
    1  &0 
\end{bmatrix} 
**Case n = 3 :** The first four are symmetric. So, they are diagonalizable . I'm not sure about the remaining two.
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  &0 &0 \\
    0  &1 &0\\
    0  &0 &1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  &0 &0 \\
    0  &0 &1\\
    0  &1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0  &1 &0 \\
    1  &0 &0\\
    0  &0 &1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0  &0 &1 \\
    0  &1 &0\\
    1  &0 &0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0  &0 &1 \\
    1  &0 &0\\
    0  &1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0  &1 &0 \\
    0  &0 &1\\
    1  &0 &0 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: @Git Gud Sorry. Got the point.

Comment: @GitGud I have changed the answer. Please remove the comment and let me know how to proceed further here.

Comment: Done. I don't think your approach is the right way to go because it doesn't seem to help on how to make a distinction between diagonalizability over $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R$. Also I get the feeling that an elementary solution is expected.